# Manifest with twitter bootstrap stays cached even if page requires another manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, browser-cache

system: rails 4, ruby 1.9.3.

I have multiple asset pipeline manifests for different layouts. Admin layout has twitter bootstrap in it, others don't.

When I access admin layout and then click on a link which leads to another layout with different manifest, old manifest is being loaded from cache (the one with twitter bootstrap) instead of new manifest file. If i refresh the page, correct manifest is loaded. So basically manifest with twitter bootstrap stays there no matter what and no other manifest can override it unless page gets refreshed.

UPDATE: This problem is not present on Safari. Problem exists on Firefox & Chrome.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I guess you are in development env and after `rake assets:precompille`?

Comment: I have the same issue on production env with rake assets:precompile on dev I have assets debug true

Comment: Updated initial post regading browsers

Comment: In develpoment , I would advice you to not precompile assets . You can undo precompilation by `rake assets:clean` . It will remove everything from `public/assets` and asset-pipeline is in charge . For the production : can you check in your Capfile the setting `load 'deply/assets' ` ?

Comment: In dev, all assets are compiling on the fly. Tried your solution and it didn't do any change. And strangely everything works fine on Safari. It seems that problem is connected to cache handling on different browsers.

Comment: Are you saying , that you have content in `public/assets` in development?

Comment: As of now, it has nothing to do with files in public/assets. The manifest file is not being loaded correctly - when link is pressed, cached manifest css file is loaded instead of the new manifest loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem was tubrolinks.js file inclusion in admin/application.js manifest. I guess it was present there as a default inclusion by twitter bootstrap. This file is supposed to tweak caching, but in my case it was making problems.